# WSO2 IS 5.10 Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712 - Solved

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

After add configuration for enable WSO2 Is-Analytics v5.8.0 in deployment.toml file in the IS_HOME/repository/conf/ directory

> https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/learn/configuring-identity-analytics/

And than running wso2server.bat IS_HOME/bin directory.
When trying to access the application in service provider, an error was found
[image]

any advice how to fix an error?
thank you

Comment: What's the cause by down in the stack trace? PKIX path building failure?

Comment: And both the servers run under the localhost hostname right? Did you change anything in the default Key Stores (wso2carbon.jks)?

Comment: One possible reason is you need to configure the certificates. A possible quick temporary fix. Copy the wso2carbon.jks and the client-truststore.jks from IS distribution located at <IS-HOME>/repository/resources/security and replace the two in the IS-Analytics distribution at <IS-ANALYTICS-HOME>/resources/security

Comment: Hi Janak, great solution. I copied the wso2carbon.jks and the client-truststore.jks and it worked. in the wso2is command window there is no error "Cannot borrow client for ssl: // localhost: 7712" again.
but in the wso2 is-analytics command window there is still an error "Error while SSL handshake: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown". any advice how to fix an error? thank you

Comment: Are you trying this with Chrome? Can you try to access the is-analytics dashboard from a different browser and see whether you still getting this certificate_unknown error.

Comment: Hi Ashensw, this problem has been solved. thank you

Answer (score 0):

First step
Configure according to the following link for analytics https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/learn/configuring-identity-analytics/

Second step
Copy the wso2carbon.jks and the client-truststore.jks from IS distribution located at `<IS-HOME>`/repository/resources/security and replace the two in the IS-Analytics distribution at `<IS-ANALYTICS-HOME>`/resources/security

if you find an error a certificate when accessing the analytics dashboard via the browser, you can try this solution
`keytool -import -alias wso2 -file "D:\localhost.pem" -keystore "C:\Program Files\WSO2\Identity Server\5.10.0\repository\resources\security\client-truststore.jks" -storepass wso2carbon`

`keytool -import -alias wso2 -file "D:\localhost.pem" -keystore "C:\Program Files\WSO2\wso2is-analytics-5.8.0\resources\security\client-truststore.jks" -storepass wso2carbon`